# Item not iterable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, iterable

I try to create a search function and filter function widt javascript..
I get the data from Firebase.

Maybe i'm just tired, but I can't reach "this.retter" because it is not iterable..
Can anyone help - how can i reference to this list of data? :-)

```js
//CLASS AND READ

    class MadService {
  constructor() {
    this.foodRef = firebaseDB.collection("madretter");
    this.userRef = firebaseDB.collection("users");
    this.authUser;
    this.authUserRef;
    this.retter;
    this.read();
  }

  read() {
    // SE DATABASEN OM DER ER ÆNDRINGER
    this.foodRef.onSnapshot(snapshotData => {
      let retter = [];
      snapshotData.forEach(doc => {
        let ret = doc.data();
        ret.id = doc.id;
        retter.push(ret);
      });
      this.appendFood(retter);
    });
  }



//SEARCH FUNCTiONALITY
      //SØGEFUNKITONEN
  search(value) {
    let searchQuery = value.toLowerCase();
    let searchFood = [];
    for (let ret of this.retter) {
      let overskrift = ret.name.toLowerCase();
      if (overskrift.includes(searchQuery)) {
        searchFood.push(ret);
      }
    }
    console.log(searchFood);
    this.appendFood(searchFood);
  }
```

Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`this.retter` is `undefined` in your code. You need to initialize it to an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) at some point before attempting to iterate over it. Below is an example of initializing it to an array (notice `this.retter = [];` in the constructor).

I added `addPhonyData` method and commented out a few things so the code works for an example:

```js
//CLASS AND READ

class MadService {
  constructor() {
    this.foodRef; // = firebaseDB.collection("madretter");
    this.userRef; // = firebaseDB.collection("users");
    this.authUser;
    this.authUserRef;
    this.retter = [];
    //this.read();
    this.addPhonyData();
  }

  read() {
    // SE DATABASEN OM DER ER ÆNDRINGER
    this.foodRef.onSnapshot(snapshotData => {
      let retter = [];
      snapshotData.forEach(doc => {
        let ret = doc.data();
        ret.id = doc.id;
        retter.push(ret);
      });
      this.appendFood(retter);
    });
  }

  addPhonyData() {
    this.retter.push({
      name: 'DuMMy'
    });
  }

  search(value) {
    let searchQuery = value.toLowerCase();
    let searchFood = [];
    for (let ret of this.retter) {
      let overskrift = ret.name.toLowerCase();
      if (overskrift.includes(searchQuery)) {
        searchFood.push(ret);
      }
    }
    console.log(searchFood);
    //this.appendFood(searchFood); - not defined
  }
}

const ms = new MadService();

ms.search('dummy');
```

Comment: But I have an appendFood()-function:
  appendFood(retter) {
    let htmlTemplate = "";
    for (let ret of retter) {
      htmlTemplate += `
      <article>
       Blablabla...
      </article>
      `;
    }
    document.querySelector('#mad-container').innerHTML = htmlTemplate;
  }



Why can i reach this?